# Inequality for $|x| \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

For $|x|\geq 1$, is the following inequality true?
$$
|x|^8\leq(1+(|x|^2-1)^4)^\frac{n+2s}{8}.
$$
I have tried assuming such an inequality holds and end up checking with the following inequality for $|x|\geq 1$:
$$
\frac{2x^4}{x^4+1}\geq 2x^2-1.
$$
Still there is doubt whether the second hold. Can somebody please help me solving this issue. Thanks.
Here $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0<s<1$.

Comment: It seems extra faulty $n=1$, $s=0.5$, $x=10$. And the second is extra faulty.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible for all $n\geq 2$?

Comment: No the point is the exponant of the right side may be bigger than the one here $8$ of the left when $n$ is for example $8$ or $9$. I mean the inequality turns true if  $n> 8$  maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the inequality does not hold.

If $|x| > 1$, the inequality is written as
$$\frac{4\ln |x|^2}{\ln (1 + (|x|^2-1)^4)} \le \frac{n+2s}{8}.$$
This inequality does not hold since 
$$\lim_{|x|^2 \to 1^{+}} \frac{4\ln |x|^2}{\ln (1 + (|x|^2-1)^4)}
= \lim_{y\to 1^{+}} \frac{4\ln y}{\ln (1 + (y-1)^4)} = 
\lim_{y\to 1^{+}} \frac{\frac{4}{y}}{\frac{4(y-1)^3}{1 + (y-1)^4}} = \infty$$
where L'Hopital's Rule is used.